# Pass a function with any case class return type as parameter

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, case-class, classtag

This might be a silly question but I've been struggling for quite some time. It is indeed similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53591578/passing-case-class-into-function-arguments) but I wasn't able to apply it in my code (duo to patterns or being a function).

I want to pass a flatMap (or map) transform function to a function argument and then proxy it to a strategy function that actually calls the df.rdd.flatMap method. I'll try to explain!

```
case class Order(id: String, totalValue: Double, freight: Double) 
case class Product(id: String, price: Double) 

... or any other case class, whatever one needs to transform a row into ...
```

The Entity class:

```
class Entity(path: String) = {
  ...
  def flatMap[T](mapFunction: (Row) => ArrayBuffer[T]): Entity = {
      this.getStrategy.flatMap[T](mapFunction)
      return this
  }
  def save(path: String): Unit = {
      ... write logic ...
  } 
}
```

An Entity might have different strategies for its methods. EntityStrategy is as follows:

```
abstract class EntityStrategy(private val entity: Entity,
                              private val spark: SparkSession) {
  ...
  def flatMap[T](mapFunction: (Row) => ArrayBuffer[T])
  def map[T](mapFunction: (Row) => T)
}
```

And one sample EntityStrategy implementation:

```
class SparkEntityStrategy(private val entity: Entity, private val spark: SparkSession)
  extends EntityStrategy(entity, spark) {
  ...
  override def map[T](mapFunction: Row => T): Unit = {
    val rdd = this.getData.rdd.map(f = mapFunction)
    this.dataFrame = this.spark.createDataFrame(rdd)
  }

  override def flatMap[T](mapFunction: (Row) => ArrayBuffer[T]): Unit = {
    var rdd = this.getData.rdd.flatMap(f = mapFunction)
    this.dataFrame = this.spark.createDataFrame(rdd)
  }
}
```

Finally, I would like to create a flatMap/map function and call it like this:

```
def transformFlatMap(row: Row): ArrayBuffer[Order] = {
    var orders = new ArrayBuffer[Order]
    var _deliveries = row.getAs[Seq[Row]]("deliveries")
    _deliveries.foreach(_delivery => {
       var order = Order(
           id = row.getAs[String]("id"),
           totalValue = _delivery.getAs("totalAmount").asInstanceOf[Double])
      orders += order
    })
   return orders
}

val entity = new Entity("path")
entity.flatMap[Order](transformFlatMap).save("path")
```

Of course, this doesn't work. I get an error on SparkEntityStrategy:

> Error:(95, 35) No ClassTag available for T
>       val rdd = this.getData.rdd.map(f = mapFunction)

I have tried adding an `(implicit encoder: Encoder: T)` to both entity and strategy methods but it was a no go. Probably done something wrong as I'm new to Scala.

If I remove the "T's" and pass an actual case class everything works fine.

Answer (score 3):

Turns out in order for both the compiler and Spark's methods to be satisfied I needed to add the following type tags:

[`T <: scala.Product : ClassTag : TypeTag`]

So both methods became:

```
def map[T <: Product : ClassTag : TypeTag](mapFunction: (Row) => T): Entity
def flatMap[T <: scala.Product : ClassTag : TypeTag](mapFunction: (Row) => TraversableOnce[T]): Entity
```

---

About [scala.Product](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.1/scala/Product.html):

> Base trait for all products, which in the standard library include at
>   least scala.Product1 through scala.Product22 and therefore also their
>   subclasses scala.Tuple1 through scala.Tuple22. In addition, all case
>   classes implement Product with synthetically generated methods.

Since I am using a case class object as my function's return type, I needed the ***scala.Product*** so that Spark's **createDataFrame** could match the correct overload.

Why both ***ClassTag*** and ***TypeTag***?

By removing the ***TypeTag***, the compiler throws the following error:

> Error:(96, 48) No TypeTag available for T
>       this.dataFrame = this.spark.createDataFrame(rdd)

And removing the ***ClassTag***:

> Error:(95, 35) No ClassTag available for T
>       val rdd = this.getData.rdd.map(f = mapFunction)

Adding them made both methods satisfied and everything worked as expected.

Found a [good article](https://medium.com/@sinisalouc/overcoming-type-erasure-in-scala-8f2422070d20) explaining type erasure in Scala.